# Kick off all other users who are logged in?

Tags: command-line, ssh, login, user-management, killall

I know if I type `w` I can get a list of all logged in users.

I also know that `killall -u USERNAME` kicks all processes associated with the user `USERNAME` (including bash / their shell, their sshd process, etc). As far as I know this is how you're supposed to "kick a user off" your server.

However I don't know how to kick off all users. Do I have to somehow `w | cut -d' ' -f1` to get a list of users (and then somehow strip off the blank line and USER field and your own username) and feed that to the -u command for `killall`?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: How about `shutdown -h now`? ;)

Comment: Do you know of [`kick`](http://old-blog.ooz.ie/2008/05/bash-kick-quick-way-to-get-rid-of.html)? Something like `kick tty pts/*` might come in handy…

Comment: @dessert I don't want to boot myself off, just everyone else

Comment: @dessert Any comment on the script I wrote / posted as answer? Are there any gaping weaknesses in it?

Comment: I recommend http://www.shellcheck.net!

Comment: What users are you trying to kick off ? system users such a www-data ?

Answer (score 2):

You can kill'm all with:

```
who | awk '$1 !~ /root/{ cmd="/sbin/pkill -KILL -u " $1; system(cmd)}'
```

You need to be root or use sudo.

Mind that killing all users can be dangerous and damage your file system. Plus annoy your users; what do you expect to happen if one of them is doing something like mysql maintenance when you kill them?

You really should use `ps -ef | grep "user"` or something similar to inspect their processes.

Why not warn them instead?

```
shutdown -h +10 "Server is going down 10 minutes. Save your work and logout."
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `awk`, what is that doing? I assume `$1` refers to the first field / the username

Comment: Yes it gets you the 1st column from the command before it (in this case who, so the user)

Comment: What happens if a user has several sessions opened? How about `who | awk '$1 !~ /root/ && l != $1 { l = $1; cmd="/sbin/pkill -KILL -u " $1; system(cmd) }`?

Comment: @Rinzwind If I shut down the machine then I can't do anything in there either. What I wanted to do was create `/etc/nologin` file so PAM would prevent logins, and then use `wall MESSAGE` to send a warning message to everyone, then kill all other users. Then I could delete the `nologin` file to re-enable logins.

Comment: "Mind that...." Well said!

Answer (score 1):

Wrote this script too which seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

ME=$SUDO_USER

if [[ -z $ME ]] 
then
    echo "Must run script using sudo."
    exit 1
fi

who | while read NAME REST
do
    if [[ $NAME != $ME ]]
    then
        killall -u "${NAME}"
        if [[ "$?" = "0" ]]
        then
            echo "Disconnecting ${NAME} from the system..."
        else
            echo "Could not disconnect ${NAME} from the system..."
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: `who | awk 'l!=$1{l=$1;print $1}'` ( or `who | awk '{print $1}' | uniq`) sorts out usernames that occur multiple times and only outputs them, so no need for `REST`.

Comment: Looks like I need to learn `awk`

Comment: It's worth the time, guaranteed.

Comment: I'd rather do `echo -n "Disconnecting ${NAME} …"; killall … && echo " Success." || echo " Fail."`, the output is much clearer this way and it saves an `if` statement.